# In pyspark upon calling actions on a dataframe, transformations functions are getting called multiple times for each action

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I've created PySpark script on AWS Glue(4.0) Interactive Session which is primarily used for data validation.

- Reading a data frame using Glue Dynamic Frame

```
initial_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
  format_options = {'quoteChar':'"', 'withHeader': True, 'separator': ', '},
  connection_type='s3',
  format='csv',
   connection_options={ 'paths': ['<s3_path_of_file>'], 'recurse': True}
```

- Transformation is done using ApplyMapping.apply() which is used to rename a column and change the schema of the columns

```
transformed_df = ApplyMapping.apply(
  frame=initial_df,
  mappings = [ 
     'col1', 'string', 'col1', 'integer'
     'col2', 'string', 'col2', 'float'
 ]
```

- One of the transformation which is a custom function that checks each cell value for a given type (integer, string, float...). The problem arises when a action is called on this transformed dataframe

```
def func1(row):
        result = dict()
        for col, val in row.asDict().items():
            if (isnan(val)) or (isinstance(val, schema_dict.get(col))):
                res['Success'] = np.nan
            else:
                res['Failure'] = f'cell: {val} failed during validation'
        updated_row = Row(**row.asDict(), dataqualityresult=result)
        return updated_row

spark_df = transformed_df.toDF()
validated_df = spark_df.rdd.map(func1)
new_df = validated_df.toDF()
```

- Then I'm exploding the dataqualityresult into 2 different columns eval_status & eval_result

```
exploded_df = new_df.select(
        col1, 
        col2, 
        explode('dataqualityresult').alias('eval_status', 'eval_result')
)
exploded_df.count()
```

- when adding an action(count, show, collect) func1 is triggered again and results in error on isinstance method. I tried cache() & persist() but it wasn't fruitful. further there are other transformations(filter) based on the Success/Failure

```
success_df = exploded_df.filter(new_df.eval_status == 'Success')
success_df.count()
```

- I'm still wondering why after applying cache/persist it's triggering the function?.
  Can someone help me out here?
- Fyi, Tried with UDF ended with same result

A transformed dataframe with additional columns and fetching the count based on eval_status for further transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a workaround. I used rdd.map(lambda x: function(x)) to traverse through each row in the dataframe and perform some calculations and later used filter to fetch the required data and then apply count on the filtered for further processing.
I got rid of UDF and Glue DynamicFrame and used PySpark dataframe to achieve my use-case.